# How does one figure out the exact equation of the boundary of the area the line sweeps through?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I am thinking of this question, but I am having a hard time solving this, or even easier problems related to this.

> There is a graph $y=\sin\frac{\pi}{4}x$ in the domain $0 \leq x\leq 4$. Let A and B two points on the x-axis, with distance 1 apart inside the domain. For example, lets say $A(t, 0)$ and $B(t+1, 0)$. Let C and D be two points the intersection of vertical lines $x=t$ and $x=t+1$ with $y=\sin\frac{\pi}{4}x$, respectively. So this means that $C(t, \sin\frac{\pi}{4}t)$, and $D(t+1, \sin\frac{\pi}{4}(t+1))$. Think of the line segment $CD$. If the points A and B move with distance 1 apart inside the domain, so will C and D, and therefore the line segment, too. What can we say about the boundary of the territory line segment $CD$ sweeps across?

I tried to think as the line segment of CD at a particular $t$ will be the tangent line for the area the line sweeps through. I also tried to simplify the problem, as in circles, or squares. This is what I thought for the square.

> Let $0\leq t\leq1$, and let $A(t, 0)$ and $B(0, 1-t)$. What will be the area where the line segment AB sweeps through?

I am not sure about this neither, and I am having a hard time trying to figure this out. Are there any given "structure/ways' for these kind of "sweeping" problems?

Comment: You can write the definition of any point that is swept through by the moving line segment. Then see what area your definition is describing.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t$ range over [0,3]. Let $s$ range over [0,1]. At any values of t and s, the point P directly between C and D has coordinates $$(t+s, (1-s)\sin{(\frac{\pi}{4}t)}-s\cdot \sin{\frac{\pi}{4}(t+1))})$$ Your region is the set of points described.

Now rewrite $t = x-s$, so that $$y =(1-s)\sin{(\frac{\pi}{4}(x-s))}-s\cdot \sin{\frac{\pi}{4}(x-s+1))} $$
For constant x, take $\partial y/\partial s$ to find the extrema. Don't forget the endpoints. Finally integrate over x to get your answer.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that I can write the set of points in that way, but how can I find the equation of the lower boundary in the way of  $y=f(x)$?

Comment: Edited to add more detail.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me a lot. Is this the only way for these kind of problems?

Comment: It's the only way I can think of at the moment. I've never had to calculate one before.